# Flutter create--Template module-overwrite

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design

I trying to create a new flutter project under VS Code IDE. I install the flutter extension, but not running any project its shows running status in the notification as well shows the output as follows.

```
Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (3 tries left) 
Running pub upgrade... 
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\src\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\analyzer-1.5.0".
Error (66): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (2 tries left) 
Running pub upgrade... 
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\src\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\analyzer-1.5.0".
Error (66): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left) 
Error: 'pub upgrade' still failing after 10 tries.
```